# How to get an access token from Google without an api library?

Tags: google-api, elixir, google-oauth, google-indexing-api

I am working on an Elixir Phoenix web project where I want to interact with Google's Indexing API.

Google uses OAuth2 to authenticate api requests and actually has a decent [documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/prereqs) on this.

But it only explains the process using one of the supported libraries in Python, Java, PHP or JS.

I would like to make the HTTP requests by myself to retrieve that access token. But the request format (including headers or parameters) is nowhere documented and I cannot even figure out from the libraries' source code.

I have tried requesting https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token (also other eligible URLs) in Postman with the "OAuth 2.0" request type.
But it was all just guessing and trying. All the research did not help.

Answer (score 3):

There are useful instructions including HTTP/Rest examples at [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer). Each step has the individual parameters fully documented. Here are some useful excerpts.

Send user to Google's OAuth 2.0 server. Example URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly&
 access_type=offline&
 include_granted_scopes=true&
 state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
 redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Foauth2.example.com%2Fcallback&
 response_type=code&
 client_id=client_id
```

Retreive authorization code (your domain). Example:

```
https://oauth2.example.com/auth?code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7
```

Request access token. Example:

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Use API. Example:

```
GET /drive/v2/files HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
Host: www.googleapis.com/
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried that out in Postman and it works. But when obtaining the authorization code, how can I get straight to the code, instead of getting redirect to the Google allow/ deny html interface? I do not ask users for permission. This is my very own Google developer account and the server should be able to get through this whole progress by itself.

Comment: You can't. OAuth is all about using a 3rd party to authenticate, without receiving the users' credentials yourself.

Comment: Hm okay... but how am I supposed to make my server work with the Indexing API then? Why would you let your user login in their google account to allow that my website gets indexed by Google? Do you get me? It all just does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Also, the libraries supported by Google use OAuth and they get around with it all server-side

Comment: Ah, I see. The docs are pretty confusing. It looks like in that case, you need to create a service account, and you get an access token using that. From the documentation you linked, it seems that you can authenticate as the service account using a pre-shared key, instead of doing the normal login flow. But you're right, they don't provide HTTP examples for that. It seems your only option is to look at what other libraries do :/