# Is it possible to use Firebase Cloud Messaging without an SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Google are deprecating the legacy HTTP protocol used for sending Firebase Cloud Messaging push notifications in june 2024. Their [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) only mentions how to migrate to the HTTP v1 using any of the SDK's for Node.js, Java, Python, Go or C#.

The main hurdle seems to be the authentication procedures required with HTTP v1. Looking at the guides for [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin), there also only seem to be options for Node.js, Java, Python, Go or C#.

So what if I want to use some other language which doesn't have an SDK? Can it be done with raw HTTP requests?

Answer (score 3):

The wire protocol for sending messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging through the v1 REST API is fully documented, like with this code snippet from the documentation on [sending messages to specific devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#rest):

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA

{
   "message":{
      "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
      "notification":{
        "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
        "title":"FCM Message"
      }
   }
}
```

You can write your own code that sends this message format against the same end point, and bypass the need for an SDK.

Authorizing a request to this API is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server), which says:

> The FCM HTTP v1 API authorizes requests with a short-lived OAuth 2.0 access token. To mint this token, you can use Google Application Default Credentials (in Google server environments) and/or manually obtain the required credentials from a JSON private key file generated for a service account.

While the documentation only contains code snippets [using SDKs to mint an OAuth 2 token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#use-credentials-to-mint-access-tokens), you can use any approach you want to get the OAuth 2 token. For example, searching for [get an oath 2 token from google without sdk](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+an+oath+2+token+from+google+without+sdk) leads to this promising result : [How to get an access token from Google without an api library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57380073/how-to-get-an-access-token-from-google-without-an-api-library).

These also looks promising:

- [Getting Firebase Bearer token by simple HttpCall (Postman)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174288/getting-firebase-bearer-token-by-simple-httpcall-postman)
- [What Bearer token should I be using for Firebase Cloud Messaging testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399170/what-bearer-token-should-i-be-using-for-firebase-cloud-messaging-testing) This shows how to get the token through the Google OAuth Playground, which allows you to inspect the raw HTTP calls that makes.
- [OAuth2 access token via rest/http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341945/oauth2-access-token-via-rest-http)